# How do I convert a "jar:file" URI to the path of Jar file?

Tags: java, uri

How do I go from `jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/test.jar!/foo/bar` to a `File` that points to `C:/Program Files/test.jar`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following code works for me (based on [How do I get just the jar URL from a jar: URL containing a "!" and a specific file in the jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402683/how-do-i-get-just-the-jar-url-from-a-jar-url-containing-a-and-a-specific-file/402771#402771)):

```
URL url = new URL("jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/test.jar!/foo/bar");
JarURLConnection connection = (JarURLConnection) url.openConnection();
File file = new File(connection.getJarFileURL().toURI())
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this.This works

```
ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
URL url = loader.getResource("resource name");
String[] filePath = null;
String protocol = url.getProtocol();
if(protocol.equals("jar")){
    url = new URL(url.getPath());
    protocol = url.getProtocol();
}
if(protocol.equals("file")){
    String[] pathArray = url.getPath().split("!");
    filePath = pathArray[0].split("/",2);
}
File required = new File(FilePath[1]);
```