# java.io.FileNotFoundException (Not a directory) when attempting to access a .wav file

Tags: java, jar, filepath

This is related to my previous question in that it is the same scenario, just one step further.

I have a testing class called `Sample` which is a simple wrapper for a `Wave` object from the musicg library:

```
import com.musicg.wave.Wave;

public class Sample {

    private String filename;
    private Wave wave;
    private WaveHeader waveheader;

    public Sample(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
        wave = new Wave(this.filename);
        waveheader = wave.getWaveHeader();
    }
}
```

I am trying to initialize a `Sample` object by passing an absolute path to the constructor. This works within Eclipse. But once I export a runnable Jar file, I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException upon passing a path to a .wav file that is included in the Jar file. Here's what I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/stas/Documents/java/workspace/EclipseTest/EclipseTest.jar/ORGCSDH1.wav (Not a directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at com.musicg.wave.Wave.<init>(Wave.java:60)
    at stm.vst.test.Sample.<init>(Sample.java:14)
    at stm.vst.test.Test.populateSamples(Test.java:70)
    at stm.vst.test.Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

What I am stumped by is the `(Not a directory)` part. This is not very helpful, as obviously it shouldn't be a directory, either. This is different from a File not Found exception. The file is verifiably there.

I should remark that I am new to runnable Jar files, so I am sure there is something very simple I am missing.

Comment: because the following is not a directory: `/Users/stas/Documents/java/workspace/EclipseTest/EclipseTest.jar/`

Comment: `EclipseTest.jar` is probably a jar file rather than a directory so you can't include it in a file path like that.

Comment: You must pass a relative path

Comment: RIGHT. I knew it was something extremely simple. So the approach of passing an absolute path to the constructor is flawed to begin with, and I should be passing a relative path based on where the class file resides, from what I understand? Apologies if my terminology is off.

Comment: Just pass the relative path /ORGCSDH1.wav, it should result in /Users/stas/Documents/java/workspace/EclipseTest/ORGCSDH1.wav (where the *.jar is)

Answer (score 0):

When resources are packed into jar files they are not available as file on HDD but only as resources; follow [Java Images not drawn when running java -jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250236/java-images-not-drawn-when-running-java-jar/18250364#18250364) as well as [How do I convert a "jar:file" URI to the path of Jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014099/how-do-i-convert-a-jarfile-uri-to-the-path-of-jar-file?lq=1)