# Opening a document outside a jar in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, jar

I have a xsl file in a jar. I also have a XML file named *language.xml* that is located next to the jar.

In the xsl, I want to load the XML document. This is how I am trying to achieve this:

```
<xsl:variable name="strs" select="document('../language.xml')/LanguageFile/Strings"/>
```

But the xml file is never loaded. Is it possible to have one file in a jar and the other outside or must they be both inside/outside the jar ??

Answer (score 0):

The call to the `document` function attempts to resolve the URI reference `../language.xml` relative to the URI of the stylesheet itself. If the stylesheet is in a jar file, the stylesheet URI is probably of the form `jar:file:/path/to/your.jar!/stylesheet.xsl`.

You cannot get the reference to the jar file itself or its directory from such a URI by just resolving a relative reference; you would need to do it [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402683/how-do-i-get-just-the-jar-url-from-a-jar-url-containing-a-and-a-specific-fi).

Probably the easiest way to refer to your XML file would be to just use a file URI instead.

If you know the full path of the file:

```
document('file:/path/to/language.xml')
```

Alternatively, if the full path is not known and fixed but you can control the current working directory, you could reference the file relative to the current working directory:

```
document('file:language.xml')
```

Comment: What if the xml file's parent is a sibling of the jar's parent. Can I do something like `document('file:../lang/language.xml')` ? Or as you suggested, I must do it programmatically and give it to the XSL as a variable ?